# SignalR how to correctly use GetHubContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am making a site in MVC Net Framework 4.8.1 and I am stuck in creating notifications.The problem is when I try to call SignalR and what I get back in the javascript is undefined.

I'll put the code below.

Hub:

```
public async Task Notify()
{
    var mongo = new Mongo();
    var invitations = await mongo.GetCountInvitations(LoginController._username);

    Clients.All.GetCountInvitations(invitations.Count);
}
```

Controller:

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
context.Clients.All.GetCountInvitations();
```

Js:

```
$(function () {
    var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

    chat.client.GetCountInvitations = function (result) {

        console.log(result)
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        chat.server.notify()
    });
});
```

The first time I enter the page the Notify method works and I get a number back in the console.log().

However, when I try to call it up via this code, it gives me undefined in the console.log():

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
context.Clients.All.GetCountInvitations();
```

Comment: **Where** are you calling `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();` ?

Comment: `.GetCountInvitations();` <-- You aren't calling `GetCountInvitations` with any arguments -that's why `result` is `undefined` in JS.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to thanks @Dai for his help.
The problem was that I did not put any arguments in and as a result it returned undefined.
I solved it with this code here:

```
var invitations = await mongo.GetCountInvitations(user.Name);
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>(); 
context.Clients.User(user.Name).GetCountInvitations(invitations.Count);
```